# How is the torque reaction in a four-stroke engine produced?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Assuming we have a plane with a propeller driven by an engine like [this one](http://selair.selkirk.bc.ca/training/aerodynamics/graphics/piston-turn-propeller.gif) .
How would the torque reaction be generated if the piston is aligned with the plane center of mass? What I mean is, where are the reaction forces located, in which part of the engine?

Comment: The image is a dead link for me.  Can you link to a `imgur.com` image?

Answer (score 1):

There are many books about this subject so your solution wont have much affect, but I agree, down-voting without any explanation isn't in the spirit of this site.

Anyway...
The pistons are reciprocating, not rotating so they contribute very little if any torque. Also, they are often in pairs of equal and opposite acceleration vectors so their forces often cancel.

The torque force is about the rotating mass - the crankshaft assembly.
This effect can be seen easily when the engine of a powerful car is revved while the car is stationary: the entire engine rotates about the crankshaft against the (often rubber) engine mounts in the engine bay.

In a single- prop plane this torque reaction makes the plane want to bank.

[this link gives an overview of the effect of the torque and how plane or pilot counteracts it.](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/dynamics/q0015a.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

The Pistons apply the force on one side of the cylinder wall.
Which side depends on the rotational direction of that particular engine.

Answer (score -1):

Lets see, the engine applies torque (pistons or not it does not matter) and if an equal and opposite reaction from the air is applied to the propeller then the engine speed is constant. In general, the torque imbalance between the engine and the drag torque results in engine acceleration or deceleration.

And that is the story about torques. If you are talking about a force imbalance or reaction forces then I suggest you edit the title and make it clear what you are asking for. The reaction forces go through the engine mount, or the engine would fly away on its own!